# Using executable from anaconda constructor, activating environment

Tags: windows-10, python, anaconda

I am trying to get some python software to a windows machine with no access to internet. To do this, I made an executable of software needed in anaconda using constructor. It installs fine, but when I try to run python it says that the environment has to be activated. But when I tried to install anaconda for that environment and make an executable, constructor refused saying that there were conflicts. Conda was installed on it's own.

Steps taken:

```
conda install opencv tensorflow-gpu keras spyder pandas
```

Create an environment.yaml file; defaults did not work, used these channels instead:

```
http://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free
http://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge
```

```
conda list -e > req.txt
(This gives me the list of packages for construct.yaml)
```

```
constructor [directory-with-construct.yaml]
```

Trying to activate an environment after installation, it tells me to initialize the shell.

Trying to do that with:

```
/directory/_conda.exe init cmd.exe
```

Gives

```
Warning: Cannot install xonsh wrapper without a python interpreter in prefix: [some-local-directory]
needs sudo ... (but this is windows!)
```

So either, how do I get anaconda on an environment to work with constructor;
or, how do I activate an environment in conda after installation?